# Game theory textbooks/lectures/etc

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

I looking for good books/lecture notes/etc to learn game theory. I do not fear the math, so I'm not looking for a "non-mathematical intro" or something like that. Any suggestions are welcome. Just put here any references you've seen and some brief description and/or review. Thanks.

Edit: I'm not constrained to any particular subject. Just want to get a feeling of the type of books out there. Then I can decide what to read. I would like to see here a long list of books on the subject and its applications, together with reviews or opinions of those books.

Comment: For those who _do_ fear the math -like me- one can always perhaps seek solace musing Joker's social experiment in _Dark Knight_? 

A non-technical book that I enjoyed was László Mérő's _Moral Calculations : Game Theory, Logic and Human Frailty_

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/76096/13733

Answer (score 9):

Game theory is a very broad subject, you should also know what you intend to use this knowledge for. Anyway, the link below contains video lectures from Yale professor Benjamin Polak. It is given as an introduction to game theory course and contains very good material. Hope this helps, cheers. http://academicearth.org/speakers/benjamin-polak

Answer (score 7):

If you are not affraid of math then i recommend:
Osborne, Rubinstein: Course in game theory

If you need more examples and more introductory style then:
Osborne: Introduction to game theory

These books do not cover combinatorial game theory and differential games.

Comment: "A course in game theory" is freely (legally) available on http://theory.economics.utoronto.ca/books/index.php/index, although you've to register. I downloaded it and it seems worth it. Thanks.

Comment: @becko  link is broken

Answer (score 5):

Yale has their past Game Theory class available for download on iTunes as well as all the class materials (hand outs, homework, tests, etc) for free from http://oyc.yale.edu/economics/game-theory/

That's where I learned what I knew about Game Theory. Its very well put together and gives a very good overview of the subject.

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 4):

I like Binmore's *Playing For Real*.  I think it's a pretty good introduction to classical game theory.

If you don't mind a very old (but classic!) book, then Luce and Raiffa's *Games and Decisions* is another text one can look at.

I also second the Watson recommendation.

Would you like to clarify on specifically what type of game theory text are you looking for?  Binmore is a pretty broad treatment, but then there are many different branches of game theory that one can go into, which all have pretty good texts.

Answer (score 3):

If you read French, I recommend you Gaël Giraud, *La théorie des jeux*, Champs Essais, Flammarion, 2009.

It is a real text in which the principles of Game Theory are exposed clearly.

I don't know if this text is translated in another language.

Answer (score 2):

I recently saw this book and seems very interesting:

John Maynard Smith - Evolution and the Theory of Games

Haven't read it yet, but I'm planning to do it ASAP. It says on the preface that it is not very heavy on the mathematics, as it is intended for biologists. From what I've seen, this book dwells in more detail in the sort of theories put forth in the famous and popular book by Richard Dawkins, The Selfish Gene.

Answer (score 0):

Coursera.org offers an excellent game theory course by Dr.s Shoham, Leyton-Brown, and Jackson (https://www.coursera.org/course/gametheory).