# Can you gave me a good book to learn game theory from A to Z?

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, book-recommendation

I want to learn game theory. I am a beginner and I do not know where I should begin. Can you gave me a good book to learn game theory from A to Z?

Comment: "Game theory" does not uniquely define a subject. For a particular type of game theory, **Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays** (multiple volumes) by Berlekamp, Conway, and Guy is the go-to source—and it's a fantastic read as well.

Comment: Following Greg Martin's comment, game theory encompasses many subjects: you might want to be more precise about what interests you and at what level.

Answer (score 0):

"From A to Z" I'd recommend *Game Theory* by Michael Maschler, Eilon Solan, and Shmuel Zamir.

You can find a commented bibliography at this link:
https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2014/09/02/guide-to-game-theory-books/

Also see
[Game theory textbooks/lectures/etc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44246/game-theory-textbooks-lectures-etc)
and
[Game theory - self study](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76096/game-theory-self-study)